# Wordpress hotspots - image popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have an image of a graphical map which I have uploaded to wordpress.  I would like to somehow create "hotspots" on this map, so that when a certain "hotspot / area" on the map is selected, then information about that location is displayed in a "popup" window. 
I have been able to accomplish this in Dreamweaver using ApDiv containers / show and hide behaviors on difference hotspots, but this involves javascript and additional css which I do not know how to incorporate into Wordpress.

Is there a way to accomplish hotspots with popup images in wordpress?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you